# Vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php:722

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, has-one

I got stuck with one to one relation
[image: Error View]
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Class 'App\App\User' not found (View: /var/www/html/project1/resources/views/pengajuan/datauser/index.blade.php)
http://app.web/pengajuan/datauser

my User Model

```
public function dataUser()
{
  return $this->hasOne(App\DataUser::class);
}
```

my DataUser Model

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
}
```

my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $datauser = DataUser::all();
    return view('pengajuan.datauser.index', compact('datauser'));
}
```

and my index view

```
@foreach ($datauser as $d)
 <td>{{$d->masa_penilaian}}</td>
 <td>{{$d->user->nama}}</td>
 <td>{{$d->nip}}</td>
 <td>{{$d->nuptk}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Can Help Me?

Thanks

Comment: could you try `DataUser::class` instead of `App\DataUser::class` and `User::class` instead of `App\User::class`?

Comment: thanks @UzairRiaz, that is my problem I use doble class on model

Comment: I will post this as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DataUser::class` instead of `App\DataUser::class` and `User::class` instead of `App\User::class`?